# Difference between variable declared before or during method call in Python

Tags: python, numpy, variables, methods

This code produces the correct result (i.e only John's):

```
import numpy as np
choices = ["John", "Adam", "Anna", "Joe", "Sebastian", "Julius"]
print(np.random.choice(choices,10, p = [1,0,0,0,0,0]))
```

While this code does not (produces anything with seemingly equal probability):

```
import numpy as np
p = [1,0,0,0,0,0]
choices = ["John", "Adam", "Anna", "Joe", "Sebastian", "Julius"]
print(np.random.choice(choices,10, p))
```

Why does the first work but not the second? Why is there a difference between variable declared before or during method call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature for [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) is:

```
 numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
```

In your first call, you are passing a value for `p`.  In your second call, you are using your `p` variable as the value for `replace`.   Change the second call to:

```
 print(np.random.choice(choices, 10, p=p))
```